# How download application in zendframe work

Tags: zend-framework

I am using zend frame works . I want to include file download section in my application. I am using this code

```
> header('Content-Type: application/doc'); header('Pragma: no-cache');
> header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$resume.'"');
> readfile(RESUME_PATH_WS . $resume);
```

But this code is not working .It return file with 0byte . Please help me how to i download files in zend frame work

Comment: What have you tried to debug this?  There's 10000 things that could be problems, so at least try to narrow it down.

Comment: i tried more than day to resolve this but no use . please suggest me any site to know more about this . very urgent issue

Comment: Just check everything that go wrong.  Look for PHP errors.  There are likely some.  My guess is that your readfile() is failing.  Meaning you should check your path.  Whenever you run into a problem like this, dissect it piece by piece from the top down until you find out *where* it's failing, then find out *why* it's failing.

Comment: @meenakshi try my answer ..since im using it else..please post the errors you are getting..which OS are you in if its linux then check for permissions

Comment: i fixed this issue by giving root path instead of direct path. thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     public function downloadAction() {

           $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
            $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

            $filename = $this->_request->getParam('filename');

            $filePath = folder/path to file/ . $filename;

            if (file_exists($filePath)) {
                $fileName = basename($filePath);
                $fileSize = filesize($filePath);


                header("Cache-Control: private");
                header("Content-Type: application/stream");
                header("Content-Length: " . $fileSize);
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fileName);


                readfile($filePath);
                exit();
            } else {
                die('The provided file path is not valid.');
            }
        }
```

Simply in your html side

```
<a href="path to your controller/downloadaction/filename/<name of file you want to download>">Download</a>
```

Comment: Using exit and die defeats the purpose of using disableLayout and setNoRender.  I would leave them enabled, and then instead of displaying a plain text error message, you could still render an error in the normal site layout (depending on the situation, I might just throw an exception and let it bubble up to the exception controller).

Comment: @corbin you are right ..i just concentrated on "how to download"

Comment: I use the exact same coding it gives error like this The provided file path is not valid.  but i am 100% sure file exist in that given path

Comment: You need to change this line "  $filePath = folder/path to file/ . $filename;
" according to your needs

Comment: And make sure file is present there also..check for permission issues

Comment: now i checking my localhost only . tat file has 777 permission

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11297/discussion-between-meenakshi-and-ubercooluk)